# Calling an method through index signature with typescript

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings

here is my function, where i am trying to call a method using `indexed signature`. it works if i added the function name manually. but how to call it using object notation. it requires for make dynamic calls.

```
 createFormControl(formControls:PatientFormProps[]):void {
    for (const control  of formControls) {
      const newPatientFormControl = new FormControl();
      if (control.options.required) {
        const value = { label: 'email' };
        newPatientFormControl.setValidators([Validators.required, PatientFormService.formProps["email"]]);//works
        newPatientFormControl.setValidators([Validators.required, PatientFormService.formProps[value.label]);//error
      }
      this.patientForm.addControl(control.key, newPatientFormControl);
    }
    console.log(this.patientForm);
  }
```

error:

```
Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type 'string' can't be used to index type '{ email: () => { error: boolean; }; }'.
  No index signature with a parameter of type 'string' was found on type '{ email: () => { error: boolean; }; }'.ts(7053)
```

the method i am trying to call is here:

```
export class PatientFormService {

  static formProps = {
    "email": () => {
      console.log('email control');
      return { error: true };
    }
  }
}
```

Here is my try with typescript playground. where i am getting similar error:

[typescript playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBCBGMC8MDeAoGW5gKYC4ByAW1ygAsQATARkPQF911gAbAQwghmIE83O3DNhjR2UAJbAeZSrQAUAN3asArgWgAnCWADmASmEjsoSCFa4AdKxC6lK9fszYmTU9BjtkMQuFyEAbhZwDwQAK29UAA98diZ0PgEuAG0EVPgwyyiAXWz5QnIJKKjCfQCgA)

**UPDATE:**

As such robby, i tried this:

```
createFormControl(formControls:PatientFormProps[]):void {
    for (const control  of formControls) {
      const newPatientFormControl = new FormControl();
      if (control.options.required) {
        const { key } = { ...control };//getting only needed key
       newPatientFormControl.setValidators([Validators.required, PatientFormService.formProps[key as const]]);//not works
      }
      this.patientForm.addControl(control.key, newPatientFormControl);
    }
    console.log(this.patientForm);
  }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to add a [`const` assertion](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-4.html#const-assertions):

```
export class PatientFormService {
  static formProps = {
    "email": () => {
      console.log('email control');
      return { error: true };
    }
  };
}

const value = { label: 'email' } as const;

PatientFormService.formProps[value.label]();
```

Comment: getting an error, while use dynamic values: `const value = control.key as const;` control key from the loop array

Comment: I'm afraid that's not how it works. You'd have to use the `const` assertion at the place you define your `control`.

Comment: can you check my update? i am getting the key from object, and using as const. still throw the error. may be the way i do is wrong? do not mind can you please help here?

Comment: You have to use the `const` assertion at the location where you define that `formControls` array that you pass to the function.

Comment: Not getting clarity. any further help or code snippet?

Comment: This entire process would be a lot easier if you could provide a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). I cannot help further without knowing, for example, the definition of `PatientFormProps`.

Comment: Here is the demo : https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-yffxvj?file=src/app/app.module.ts

Comment: Ah, I understand the problem now. I'd just add some type information and refactor as follows: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-ptragd?file=src%2Fapp%2Fform.service.ts

Comment: can you share me the issue in answer? so it will help others

Answer (score 0):

Another way to do it would be to define a union type of all the allowed values, and then use that type to constrain the type of `value` in your example (`{ label: 'email' }` has the type `{ label: string }`).

Here's a utility type that does basically that:

```
type StaticMethodNames<T> = { [K in keyof T]: T[K] extends Function ? K : never }[keyof T]
```

Here's your simplified example on [TS Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAysCGwCWBjAshYALA9gEwDl4BbCAZwB4AVAPigF4oBvKAbQGkokA7KAawggcAMyhUAugC4xHcVAgAPYBG54yUAGIBXbimQ5eAfiidp3CADcIAJygBfVgKGiJAKFcoDZYFBwAjaQAlCE9rPApvax4AcwAaWARkdExcQhJyClBIEShiEBQAG3gyMho6RiZXKGrfc0kAclJsfABGetc7d0Li9TzukuYqmu9EVFyU1oAKC3gCrQhJSJiASkqa9ahPbjIcAogAOgKcaOnZ+eWh6s7Ore8oeAYoeoMIeoBuDy8ffwArR6YFJJ4J1XH0iiVWP5IX4fvsFOJxJN6lgkAoFPVlm8gA), updated to use this method to resolve the "Element implicitly has an 'any' type" error message you were getting, and here's another [TS Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAysCGwCWBjAshYALA9gEwDl4BbCAZwB4AVAPigF4oBvKAbQGkokA7KAawggcAMyhUAugC4xHcVAgAPYBG54yUAGIBXbimQ5eAfiidp3CADcIAJygBfVgKGiJAKFcoANvDLqACohIKsAaONbEMDYWqNBMrlBQZAjIKFDCYcR+1jhg6oxxCQkARBDE8EieRdIAFACUDHQFhQkoBmQ4nhAAdJ44AObVAOSl5Z5QrdzA2Z6DtQDc8c1Q1pha1rwsNtnW0lNa0HYLzXaLJycebcBQFvCe+1DSAEoQrdZ4FEnWPH0ANLDJqAw2HwRFIlFAkBEUACyGCoXCkWs0RQ3XS4SyOTINDo+Sg3gARhBPNJhmUKoN7AtXDCgpN4REojEumjMtlcqwbndugSieI6nMgA) that's a little closer to the original code you had.